# How to lock/unlock a subform

Tags: vba

I have an access database that has a form that shows information about students, name, class, course etc. On the form I have a subform that shows the grades for the students. I have an edit button with this code:

```
If Me.AllowEdits = True Then
    Me.AllowEdits = False
    Me.genderCbo.Locked = True
    Me.courseCbo.Locked = True
    Me.subfrmGrades.Locked = True

ElseIf Me.AllowEdits = False Then
    Me.AllowEdits = True
    Me.genderCbo.Locked = False
    Me.courseCbo.Locked = False
    Me.subfrmGrades.Locked = False

End If
```

But with this code, whether it is is edit mode or not, I cant edit the grades in the subform. Can someone please come up with a fix? Been searching the internet for a good 30min now and couldn't find anything.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the information about the students inserted? are they in `TextBox` or `Labels` or what?

Comment: Is the form bound or unbound?

Comment: @Jean-PierreOosthuizen In the form, labels and textboxes, in the subform the same

Comment: @GavinP subform is bound

Comment: @SebastianoAlfano-Simmons is the edit button on the subform or the main form? If it's on the main form, you need to allow edits on the subform. If not then that's not the issue.

Comment: @GavinP The button is on the main form. In the code when I type

    me.subfrmGrades 

AllowEdits doesn't show up?

Tried it anyway, and it comes back with an error saying that the method or data isn't found

Comment: try `me.subfrmGrades.Form.Allowedits=true` as well as `me.subfrmGrades.Locked=true`. Works on my test form

Comment: @GavinP Thank you a bunch! The first one works wonders! <3

Answer (score 1):

You have to reference the Form object within the subform control. To do this use `me.subfrmGrades.Form.Allowedits=true` instead of just `me.subfrmGrades.Allowedits=true`.